# How to stop running Xcode

Tags: xcode

Does anyone know how to force Xcode to stop running.  I updated to 6.2 but now its not working correctly.  I need to quit Xcode to either finish the update or uninstall and reinstall.  Quite Xcode from the menu isn't available.  Can't drag it to the trash because it says it is still running. Command Q doesn't stop it either.  Sorry, new to Mac and advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 9):

Click the Apple logo in the top left and then "Force Quit", or alternatively <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>option</kbd>+<kbd>escape</kbd>. You should be able to close the application from here.

Comment: any other one option quit Xcode me for command+option+escape but not working

Comment: @RamaniHitesh `kill $(ps aux | grep 'Xcode' | awk '{print $2}')`

Answer (score 4):

You can quit any process with Xcode in its name from command line.

`kill $(ps aux | grep 'Xcode' | awk '{print $2}')`